# Как генерировать случайные числа в шейдерах OpenGL?

Tags: opengl

Есть такая неплохая функция - `noise`. Но она по непонятным причинам не работает. Может кому-нибудь известны и другие способы генерации случайных значений?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Есть четыре шумовые функции, noise1, noise2, noise3 и noise4. Но, они не всегда поддерживаются. По этой причине, обычно используют шумовую текстуру, заранее заготовленную.

Answer (score 0):

Подсмотрел недавно на [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4200224/random-noise-functions-for-glsl) вот такую реализацию шума с входом и сидом, что достаточно удобно:

```
float PHI = 1.61803398874989484820459;  // Golden Ratio
float gold_noise(in vec2 xy, in float seed){
  return fract(tan(distance(xy * PHI, xy) * seed) * xy.x);
}
```